# Is there any sentence structure that English has but Chinese (Mandarin) does not?

Tags: syntax, comparative-linguistics

Chinese (Mandarin) translation of my question may be an example of the sentence structure that both English and Chinese share:

```
[Is there any] [sentence structure] (that) [English has but Chinese (Mandarin) does not]?
[有没有什么][句子结构][英语有但是汉语（普通话）没有]？
```

Comment: She's not a trained linguist, but my wife still claims that multiple embedding is rare in Chinese, and many of the center-embedded sentences need to be rearranged to parataxis.

Comment: @Ron Maimon It's quite true. Thx!

Comment: If it's true, maybe you can answer my question on Chinese embedding--- http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/how-did-chinese-recursion-evolve . Do you know how true it is in the 20th/19th/18th centuries? When did center embedding first appear approximately? Is it still going on, are the number of embedding constructions increasing? I wonder about this endlessly, and my wife lost patience with me on this a long time ago.

Comment: @Ron Maimon I will ask my friend who is majoring in ancient Chinese, maybe on this Saturday.  :D

Comment: any news .....?

Comment: @Ron Maimon I met him today, he said multiple embedding is impossible in ancient Chinese.

Comment: This would be an insanely great way to test how embedding catches on in a language--- I think this would make a terrific paper. Is it correct to place the first multiple embedding in the 19th century then?

Answer (score 9):

Consider preposition stranding, which is possible in English but not in Mandarin:

> the girlfriend I broke up with
>
> *跟分手的女朋友
>
> ```
> *gen  fenshou de nvpengyou
> with breakup DE girlfriend
> ```

A resumptive pronoun is obligatory in Mandarin but impossible in English:

> *the girlfriend I broke up with her
>
> 跟她分手的女朋友
>
> ```
> gen ta fenshou de nvpengyou
> with her breakup DE girlfriend
> ```

There are several other cases such that extraction out of a constituent is grammatical in English but not in Mandarin. In other words, many phrases in Mandarin including 把+NP and the aforementioned prepositional phrases seem to be extraction islands.

EDIT: I can also think of a case of the converse (a Mandarin syntactic construction which cannot be rendered in English without some circumlocution).

Comment: thx for your answer! but the example of “跟她分手的女朋友” seems not to be a valid sentence for me (I'm a native Chinese). The possible translation of "the girlfriend I broke up with" is "已经跟我分手了的女朋友". In real life, I would actually say "已经分手了的女朋友". The "跟我" is quite superfluous.

Answer (score 4):

As jogloran pointed out, preposition stranding (and how you can't do it in Chinese) is a good source of these. Here are several examples of relative clauses where the object of a preposition is being pulled out. Note that the Chinese grammar doesn't match the English (because the obvious way to do it is ungrammatical):

1. **carry a bag *for* X**

   > I'm carrying this bag for him.
   >
   > 我帮他拿这个包。 *I help him grab this CL bag*
   >
   > The person I carried this bag for is gone.
   >
   > 我帮他拿这个包的人走了。 *I help him grab this CL bag REL person leave PFV*
2. **come back *from* X**

   > I just came back from France.
   >
   > 我刚从法国回来。 *I just from France return*
   >
   > The country I just came back from uses the Euro.
   >
   > 我刚从那里回来的国家用欧元。*I just from there return REL country use Euro*
3. Literally **hit a phone *for* X**

   > I called Apple (the computer company).
   >
   > 我给苹果公司打了电话。 *I give apple company hit PFV telephone*
   >
   > The company I called makes computers.
   >
   > 我打了电话的公司是制造电脑的。 *I hit PFV telephone REL company is make computer*
4. **poke your arm *with* X**

   > I poked your arm with a chopstick.
   >
   > 我用筷子戳你的胳膊。 *I use chopstick poke you POS arm*
   >
   > The chopstick I poked your arm with is on the floor.
   >
   > 我用来戳你胳膊的筷子在地上。 *I use-come poke you (POS) arm REL chopstick located floor-on*
5. **sell my bike *to* X**

   > I sold him my bike.
   >
   > 我给他卖我的自行车。 *I give him sell I POS bike*
   >
   > The person I sold my bike to also lives in China.
   >
   > 我把自行车卖给(他?)的那个人也住在中国。*I OBJ-Marker bike sell give (him?) REL that CL person also live in China*

It seems there are a few different grammatical strategies:

- Delete the preposition (as in #3); the meaning is still clear from the context.
- Use a "dummy variable" as the object of the preposition (`他 = he` in #1 and #5, `那里 = there` in #2)
- Reverbalization of the preposition using `来 = come` (e.g., #4)

<sub>Notes on glosses:</sub>

<sub>CL = Classifier, as in the measure words in Chinese (e.g., 个).</sub>

<sub>REL = Relativizer; the 的 particle which links adjectives or relative clauses to nouns.</sub>

<sub>PFV = Perfective; the 了 particle which marks for completedness of verbs.</sub>

Comment: Glosses of the Mandarin text would be a great help for those who don't read Mandarin but would still like to follow along.

Comment: @Joe I added them. I don't have a lot of experience glossing Mandarin, so feel free to fix up the abbreviations for the particles if you so desire.

Answer (score 2):

English participial phrases and absolute clauses come to mind.

Take this sentence in English, for instance:

```
Seeing the yellow light, I slowed down.
```

The Mandarin equivalent would need to be something like this:

```
[Wǒ] [kàn-dào             huángdēng    de  shíhòu] [màn   le       xiàlai].
 I  see-EXTENT-complete  yellow light  MOD  time   slow  ASP-perf  EXTENT-down
```

It could be loosely stated as two uncoordinated verbal phrases, but they would be more disconnected than the English construction.

```
[Wǒ] [kàn-dào               huángdēng],   [wǒ] [màn  le         xiàlai].
 I    see-EXTENT-complete  yellow light    I   slow  ASP-perf   EXTENT-down
```

Which is better rendered in English as 'I saw the yellow light; I slowed down.'

A sentence using an absolute construction in English, on the other hand, does not always make sense uncoordinated in Mandarin.

> Weather permitting, I will see you tomorrow.

The conditional needs to be stated in Mandarin:

```
[Tiānqì] [yǔnxǔ   de huà],   [míngtiān  jiàn].
weather   permit    if        tomorrow   see
```

Which is more like "In the case that weather permits, I will see you tomorrow" in English.

<sub>Notes on glosses:</sub>



<sub>MOD - modifier; makes the preceding phrase modify the following phrase</sub>



<sub>EXTENT - extent marker; -complete indicates completion, and -down indicates gradual completion.</sub>



<sub>ASP - aspect marker; -perf indicates perfective.</sub>